# Java Game Dev: Timertask this snipped of code

Tags: java, timer, task

I'm making a "space-invaders style" game. You(the player) move left and right at the bottom of the screen. There will be one enemy in each window, and you have to move to the window and shoot.

I'm working on the enemies popping up system. The window in which an enemy is random and should change every 3 seconds. Here's my code for this:

```
int enemylocation = new Random().nextInt(2) +1;
    if(enemylocation==1){
        enemy1.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
        enemy1.draw(200,170,s*10);
    }
    if(enemylocation==2){
        enemy2.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
        enemy2.draw(200,360,s*10);

    }
```

Everything works, but the random number part is always picking a new number, so both windows are flickering. How can I delay the timer to change the value of enemylocation every 3 seconds and not constantly? I need to use a TimerTask because I don't have a functioning tick system.

Thanks

Comment: You've asked the same thing 5 times...

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet is missing the the TimerTask. Anyway, TimerTask has an argument with which you can set the delay, [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29).

Note this is in milliseconds, so in order to wait 1 second, set the delay to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29). I hope after this you wont repeat your question.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerDemo {
    final static Random ran = new Random();
    static int enemylocation = 0;
    static Timer tm = new Timer();
    static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        tm.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                enemylocation = ran.nextInt(2) + 1;
                System.out.println("enemylocation:" + enemylocation);
                System.out.println("time:" 
                         + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000);
            }
        }, 1, 3000);

    }

}
```

Comment: @user2302825 Figure that out my friend. I am not going to write whole thing for you. No offence but you are writing the game then you should be knowing atleast how to embed/use this code with yours. Also look at link I gave and try to understand this piece.

Comment: @user2302825 My friend have you ran this `pseudo code`. It exactly runs after every `3 seconds`.  I answered the part what you asked for `i.e.` use of `Timer`. And I haven't seen your code so I am not sure what is going wrong there.

Comment: @user2302825 I really cant tell you by the information you have given. I will suggest you to debug the code and find out where and why its going wrong. If you are using `Eclipse` then [`Eclipse Debugging Tutorials`](http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm)